# Dúvida Iniciante WHERE EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql, where

Sou iniciante no mundo SQL, estou aprendendo algumas funções e me deparei com um problema onde não consigo entender.

Tenho uma tabela `medico` com o atributo `cod_medico`. Nesse atributo há as informações: `1`, `2` e `3`.

Tenho outra tabela `paciente` com o atributo `cod_paciente` onde há as informações: `3`, `4` e `5`.

Quero buscar todos os `cod_medicos` que existem em `cod_paciente`.

Sei que a resposta correta é o do código abaixo onde ele trás a resposta `3`:

```
SELECT cod_medico 
FROM medico 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT cod_paciente FROM paciente WHERE cod_paciente = cod_medico)
```

Porém, não consigo entender o porquê que a lógica abaixo está incorreta:

```
SELECT cod_medico 
FROM medico 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT cod_paciente FROM paciente)
```

Essa resposta me retorna todos os dados do atributo `cod_medico`: `1`, `2` e `3`.

No meu entendimento, o SQL buscaria a primeira informação do atributo `cod_medico` (que seria `1`) e faria a comparação com todos os dados do atributo `cod_paciente` onde não me mostraria nada, na segunda vez faria a comparação com o valor `2` onde também não me mostraria nada e por último faria com o valor `3` onde faria a comparação e me mostraria o valor `3`.

Porém onde está o erro nessa lógica?

Talvez a maneira que eu penso não seja a mesma que o SQL se comporta.

Comment: O operador Exists retorna true se a sua subquery retornar qualquer valor, e isso ocorre quando você remove o Where pois existem dados na tabela

Comment: Acho que você talvez esteja fazendo confusão com o operador In

Comment: Está incorreta pois se existir algum registro na tabela `paciente` será a condição necessária para selecionar todos os registros da tabela `medico`. Seu exemplo é meio estranho pois você quer relacionar os dados da tabela `medico` com os dados da tabela `paciente` com base num código que na realidade não tem o mesmo significado, apesar de poderem ter valores em comum. Avalie o uso de INNER JOIN para relacionar registros das duas tabelas com um campo em comum.